# How do I make a suite of unit [and functional] browser tests?

Tags: intern

Intern says it allows [browser unit tests](https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Running-Tests#as-a-stand-alone-browser-client), in addition to [functional tests](https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Writing-Tests#functional-testing) running over webdriver.  IIUC a unit test can assume it's running in a browser and freely access document and window etc.

If I write a set of such browser unit tests, how do I run all of them and collect the results into one report?   And how would I run a set of unit tests and functional tests combined together?

Answer (score 1):

All test suites that are defined in the `suites` key of your your [Intern configuration](https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Configuring-Intern) are loaded and reported using whatever the [reporter](https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Using-Reporters) is that you’ve configured regardless of platform. The same is true of `functionalSuites` when running tests using the runner. Running tests all at once is explained in the [multi-platform section](https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Running-Tests#as-a-test-runner-for-multi-platform-testing) of the [running tests documentation](https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Running-Tests).

Comment: OK, so even though you start running the tests from node (node runner.js), the modules specified in suites[] will be executed in the browser?

Comment: That’s right. `node runner.js` invokes each browser and passes to them the configuration file that it was started with, so where the unit tests run is the same regardless of if you are using `runner.js` or loading `client.html` directly.